# Return multiple values in ternary operation vuejs

Tags: vue.js, decentralized-applications

I have a dapp built in vuejs which has the following function:

```
export function useBalanceRefetch() {
    const userStore = useUserStore();
    
    const fetchBalance = (address: string, currency: string) => {
        const fetcher = currency === 'eth' ? fetchEthBalance : fetchArbBalance;

        fetcher(address).then(balance => {
            if (balance) {
                userStore[currency === 'eth' ? 'balanceEth' : 'balanceArb'] = balance;
            }
        });
    };

    return { fetchBalance };
}
```

It all works ok but i need to add another token to it.

I tried the following:

```
export function useBalanceRefetch() {
    const userStore = useUserStore();
    
    const fetchBalance = (address: string, currency: string) => {
        const fetcher = currency === 'eth' ? fetchEthBalance ? fetchUsdtBalance : fetchArbBalance;

        fetcher(address).then(balance => {
            if (balance) {
                userStore[currency === 'eth' ? 'balanceEth' ? 'balanceUsdt' : 'balanceArb'] = balance;
            }
        });
    };

    return { fetchBalance };
}
```

But it gives me an error in:

```
const fetcher = currency === 'eth' ? fetchEthBalance ? fetchUsdtBalance : fetchArbBalance;
```

And:

```
userStore[currency === 'eth' ? 'balanceEth' ? 'balanceUsdt' : 'balanceArb'] = balance;
```

Any help would be great... i've tried to figured it out without success.

Answer (score 2):

Ternary means that are involved **three parts**.

*condition* `?` *value_if_true* `:` *value_if_false*

You can get around the obstacle nesting more ternary expressions, **but I recommend** in a limited way:

```
userStore[currency === 'eth' ? 'balanceEth' : (currency === 'usd' ? 'balanceUsdt' : 'balanceArb')] = balance;
```